# Network detected as public and DcDiag failed after restoring the 2 DCs

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

I have (small) domain with 2 (virtualized) DCs running Windows 2012 R2.

For testing purpose, I have restored them in an lab environment isolated from the production one.
This lab environment use the same ip address range, same ip for gateway and have access to internet - but  isolated from prod. env.

When I restart the 2DCs, network type is NOT detected as domain.
So I made some searchs, and I also saw that dcdiag report error (see below)
On the other hand, name resolution and ping are OK

As the Hypervisor is different from the original, the NIC were considered as a new device.
But there is still only one NIC on each DC.

Any suggestion ?

Thank you in advance.

```
C:\> dcdiag

Directory Server Diagnosis

Performing initial setup:
   Trying to find home server...
   Home Server = XS-DC-A
   * Identified AD Forest.
   Done gathering initial info.

Doing initial required tests

   Testing server: Premier-Site-par-defaut\XS-DC-A
      Starting test: Connectivity
         ......................... XS-DC-A passed test Connectivity

Doing primary tests

   Testing server: Premier-Site-par-defaut\XS-DC-A
      Starting test: Advertising
         Fatal Error:DsGetDcName (XS-DC-A) call failed, error 1355
         The Locator could not find the server.
         ......................... XS-DC-A failed test Advertising
      Starting test: FrsEvent
         There are warning or error events within the last 24 hours after the SYSVOL has been shared.  Failing SYSVOL
         replication problems may cause Group Policy problems.
         ......................... XS-DC-A passed test FrsEvent

    (continues...)
```

Comment: `This lab environment use the same ip address range, same ip for gateway and have access to internet - but isolated from prod. env` - How is that possible?

Comment: @joeqwerty : hypersivor NIC is connected to another HUB, and uses a different computer as a gateway.

Comment: FYI, my problem was solved doing this : https://www.sysadmintutorials.com/tutorials/microsoft/windows-2012/windows-2012-authoritative-restore-for-disaster-recovery/